# послать запрос POST (API) из С#

Tags: c#, post, api, xamarin

Пытаюсь послать запрос **POST** из **Xamarin**, вот текст:

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.6.13:59626/api/values");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
    WebAPI.TMessage message = new WebAPI.TMessage { sMessage = "Приветики!!!" };
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);

    //string json = "{\"x\":\"true\"}";

    streamWriter.Write(json);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    }

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
     {
     var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
     //return result;
     }
```

Метод **POST** в **API** реагирует на этот запрос, но параметр пустой. Код **API**:

```
public void Post([FromBody]string/*byte[]*/ value)
    {
    TMessage a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TMessage>(value);
    db.InsReturn(a.sMessage);
    }
```

Подскажите, что не так делаю?

Comment: А зачем вы отправляете JSON строку и затем ее десериализуете? Ведь можно сразу принимать ваш `TMessage`. Скажем `[FromBody] TMessage value`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, в этом дело было. Получается тип параметра нужно указывать объекта, который передаем...

Comment: Тут дело скорей в том, что вы указали тип отправляемых данных, как JSON, а сервер ждет обычный текст. Можно переключить на текст и будет отправлять обычную `string`, но зачем двойная конвертация, если сервер и так может понять необходимое)

Answer (score 3):

Отправляемые вами данные отличаются от того, что ожидает сервер. Ведь вы ему отправляете данные в `JSON` формате, а он ожидает от вас обычный `string`.

- Поменяйте у сервера ожидаемые данные:

  public void Post([FromBody] TMessage value)
- Уберите у сервера лишнюю строку десериализации:

  TMessage a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(value);

Вы можете пойти по другому пути и отправлять ожидаемое для сервера значение, но тогда надо в запросе поменять `ContentType` на [необходимое](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_MIME-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2).